# View binding error : Member Injector is defined multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger, android-viewbinding

I am trying to move a large scale app to view binding. we are using dagger.android at a lot of areas, so i am guessing the View Binding and dagger are not faring well. here is the error i am getting :

```
Type net.myapp.base.abstracts.vb.BaseFragmentVB_MembersInjector is defined multiple times:
Users/anshsachdeva/Desktop/android/myapp-android/feature/search/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/stagingDebug/classes.jar:net/myapp/base/abstracts/vb/BaseFragmentVB_MembersInjector.class, /

Users/anshsachdeva/Desktop/android/myapp-android/feature/flashcard/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/stagingDebug/classes.jar:net/myapp/base/abstracts/vb/BaseFragmentVB_MembersInjector.class
```

Some Context:
The app uses the classic clean architecture, where all the child activities, fragments, etc extend  from the base classes . the project is also having multiple feature modules like `app` ,`base`, `feature/search`, `feature/flashcard`,`domain` , etc . The base classes reside in `base` module, while the classes extending from them resides in their associated module like `feature/search`.

To support view binding, i added some intermediate abstract classes that would act as holders of Viewbinding :passing an inflated view to parent while handling the lifecycle of viewbinding instance and providing safe access to children, both at the same time. i kept those in base class module only.

now everything was working well and the children classes are able to access the  base View binding classes, but when i try to build the project, this error occurs. I am not sure why is this happening?

(PS:I work on several branches. the view binding code was in one of the branches. last week i made this code, built it and run , and it was working. Then i switched branches and started working on other things. this week, i come back to the same branch and code does not build )

Comment: Have you tried deleting the build folder? It could be some file that was generated by your other branch that conflicts and should be removed

Comment: @BasilePerrenoud i tried running clean on the project, but it did not helped. actually each module is generating their own build folder, which am guessing is removed when clean runs. Let me try manually cleaning them all

Comment: If it's literally the same code that worked before, it must be something about your environment right? Are any of your dependences using a non-specific version (like ``1.+``) where it might have updated? Any local libraries that might have changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou everyone. I changed my build environment from staging to debug and it worked. Now need to work on the newer problem of why the build environment is not working.

Answer (score 0):

when i run into these type of issues i sense gradle thinks everything is ok when its not and is skipping tasks. so i force gradle to rerun all tasks with this option on command line:

**`--rerun-tasks`**

Answer (score 0):

[answer 1](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/814)
[answer 2](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/955)
common or base module, in class `BaseFragmentVB` should be used `@Inject`, as a result c is generated `BaseFragmentVB_MembersInjector` in one place, the rest of the modules will use from common or base module this generated class.

Or you can try to increase the version Dagger Android

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34693963)